# PlaySpec test class not picked up if using injection

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, playframework, scalatest

In my Play 2.6.x application, I'm testing with `PlaySpec`. Now I would like to inject some object to be used in test code.

```
class AuthControllerTest @Inject()(userRepository: UserRepository)
  extends PlaySpec with GuiceOneAppPerSuite with Injecting {

  "Foo bar" should {
    "do xyz" in {
      // do something with userRepository
    }
  }
}
```

However, this class never gets picked up for tests, e.g. when running `sbt test`.

A simple workaround is to manually get the injector from the current Play instance, but `Play.current` is deprecated and it generally feels hacky:

```
class AuthControllerTest
  extends PlaySpec with GuiceOneAppPerSuite with Injecting {

  "Foo bar" should {
    "do xyz" in {
      val userRepository = Play.current.injector.instanceOf[UserRepository]
      // do something with userRepository
    }
  }
}
```

Why doesn't the former example work? And is there a cleaner approach than the latter example?

Comment: Play Framework does not do dependency injection for tests like the first example. On the second one, you don't need `Play.current` since  `GuiceOneAppPerSuite` makes an `app` available to you. So you can do `val userRepository = app.injector.instanceOf[UserRepository]`. And by using `Injecting` you can simplify it even further like `val userRepository = inject[UserRepository]`.

Comment: See also the [docs for using dependency injection in tests](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaTestingWithGuice).

Comment: @marcospereira Ah, totally makes sense. I guess that's what I've been looking for, so if you want to convert it to an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: @RichDougherty I'd seen that page before, but from what I can see this rather talks about configuring DI during tests, but not about injecting something into test classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Play Framework does not do dependency injection for tests like the first example. On the second one, you don't need `Play.current` since `GuiceOneAppPerSuite` makes an Application (`app`) available to you. So you can do:

```
val userRepository = app.injector.instanceOf[UserRepository].
```

And by using `Injecting`, you can simplify it even further like:

```
val userRepository = inject[UserRepository]
```

And from the [official docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaFunctionalTestingWithScalaTest#Creating-Application-instances-for-testing):

> If all or most tests in your test class need an Application, and they can all share the same instance of Application, mix in trait GuiceOneAppPerSuite with the GuiceFakeApplicationFactory trait. **You can access the Application from the app field**.

There is also a page about [Injecting](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaFunctionalTestingWithSpecs2#Injecting) in the official docs.